# application window title with file path for multiple main windows

Tags: python, qt, ubuntu, pyqt

I have an application with two main windows. I want both of then to have the standard title which contains the file name and application name. But this works strange because both files show the file name **but only the second window shows the application name**. The first shows just "x.py" while the second "y.py - My App". Anybody has an idea why is that and how to solve it? Is this a bug or is it expected behaviour?

```
from qtpy.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

app = QApplication([])
app.setApplicationDisplayName("My App")
wnd1 = QMainWindow()
wnd2 = QMainWindow()
wnd1.setWindowFilePath("x.py")  # in most cases it shows only "x.py" - this is wrong
wnd2.setWindowFilePath("y.py")  # correctly shows "y.py - My App"
wnd1.show()
wnd2.show()
app.exec_()
```

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04., PyQt 5.8.2.

UPDATE: So I also discovered it behaves non-deterministically. Sometimes both application titles appear correctly. Sometimes only one. This seems like a bug.

Comment: It's working fine on Windows 10 and PyQt 5.9. Seems to be a bug in PyQt/Ubuntu then.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround for this likely bug I am going to override the `setWindowFilePath()` for my main window classes. This will give me another benefit such as showing the full file path instead of just file name and also indicate that the file is unnamed if it is a new file which has not yet been saved or loaded, which is what I want anyway. It also works well with changing window-modified state. I know I am sacrificing the 100 % 'native' look but... I can live with it.

```
def setWindowFilePath(self, filePath):
    super(MainWindow, self).setWindowFilePath(filePath)
    if not filePath:
        filePath = "unnamed"
    self.setWindowTitle("{}[*] - {}".format(filePath, qApp.applicationDisplayName()))
```

Maybe somebody will find a better solution.